# How to merge two SIG files to one PKCS7 container?

Tags: c#, cryptography

Some users sign one file content using CSP (f.e. CryptoPro, Vipnet, etc).
I have one .SIG file (PKCS#7) for each signed users.

How to merge\join all .SIG files to onу file?

I can extract signedCms.SignerInfos from each files, but can't put it to new signedCms.

```
var signedBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(name);
ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(msgBytes);
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
signedCms.Decode(signedBytes);

foreach (var cmsSignerInfo in signedCms.SignerInfos)
{
    var signerInfo = cmsSignerInfo;
}
...
```